# How can I make my specific slideshow resize with the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm completely rubbish with javascript and have a slideshow which I added below and would like to have it resize according to the window size. I've tried messing around on JS fiddle but can't seem to make it work. Can anyone tell me what my code is missing here below? I know it's not right at all but can't seem to fix it, tried many websites and videos...

Here are my slideshow divs and part of the javascript, not sure if it's useful:

```
<div id="sliderFrame">
<div id="slider">
<img src="images/slide1.jpg" />
<img src="images/slide2.jpg" />
<img src="images/slide3.jpg" />
<img src="images/slide4.jpg" />
<img src="images/slide5.jpg" />
</div>
</div>

var sliderOptions=
{
sliderId: "slider",
startSlide: 0,
effect: "6,15,1,2,11,12,13,15,16,5,7",
effectRandom: false,
pauseTime: 2600,
transitionTime: 500,
slices: 14,
boxes: 11,
hoverPause: 2,
autoAdvance: true,
captionOpacity: 0.5,
captionEffect: "rotate",
thumbnailsWrapperId: null,
m: true,
license: "mylicense"
};
var imageSlider=new mcImgSlider(sliderOptions);
```

The last part of the javascript goes on for a while...
Now here is the javascript for my window resize function which is located in the same js file as my slideshow and goes as follows:

```
addLoadEvent(function() {
$(window).resize(function() { 
#sliderFrame, #slider
});
}
```

lol clearly it's missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css properties to resize the window.
I used this in one of my slides. Make sure you have absolute postion.

```
.class{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%
}
```